# Error in Huawei phone. Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.video.exoplayer3.a.b

Tags: android

I only get errors on the huawei phone
`Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.video.exoplayer3.a.b.`

I'm not an intern. So I know what is the usual NullPointerException error. In my question, the error only occurs on 1 single device and can not find details in the crashlytics report. So if you can not provide a help answer, please do not flag or report duplicates when you do not know what it is.

Comment: @RumitPatel , Please carefully read the question before reporting that it is duplicate. The content of my question is not just NullPointerException as the question you gave the link

Comment: You can have a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/X-sq-yLfIp0/UxGVbdU6AQAJ) and [this.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-help-forum/1POPpvpqoqM)

Comment: @RumitPatel 
I searched and read the problem in the path you submitted before. But it does not solve my problem. So I sent up here to hope someone answered. Thank you